# Java - Bitwise operations not getting what expected

Tags: java, binary, bit-manipulation

```
private void test2() {
    // This test takes two shorts and sticks them together in a
    // 4 bit 12 bit configuration within a short, it then breaks
    // them apart again to see if it worked!
    short s0 = 4095;
    short s1 = 13;

    short sh = (short)((s1 << 12) | s0);

    System.out.println(sh);

    short[] sa = new short[] {
        (short)(sh & 0xFFF),
        (short)((sh >>> 12) & 0xF)
    };

    System.out.println(sa[0]);
    System.out.println(sa[1]);

}
```

What I expect from this is this;

`s0` in binary is `b0000_1111_1111_1111`

`s1` in binary is `b0000_0000_0000_1101`

`sh` then becomes `b1101_1111_1111_1111`

The preceeding `1` is the sign and the remaining 15 bits gives the value so `sh` in decimal is `-24575` but this is not what I get outputted to the console (which is `-8193`).

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result is actually correct. Binary numbers are represents in what is called the 2s-complement. So to compute the absolute value of a negative number, you do not just remove the sign bit and see what remains. Rather you do this:
1. Flip all bits, including the sign bit
2. Add 1

In your case that means you get

1. 0010_0000_0000_0000
2. 0010_0000_0000_0001

Which is 8193, which  is exactly what is printed out.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation, I'll do some reading on the matter =)

Answer (score 6):

b1101_1111_1111_1111 is -8193, it is outputting the correct answer.  Might want to brush up on your 2s complements.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: My bad, I'm a Physics grad not Computer Science, thanks for your response.

Comment: indeed! There must be a reason for using 2s complements but at first glance it seems like the wrong choice lol! Thanks again.

Comment: Well think about how a computer sees it.  If you subtract 1 from 0, you expect to get -1, but it would actually end up being 1111111... which would be the max negative int how you displayed it, but it is negative 1 as 2s complement.

Comment: The reason for using 2s-complement is because of the hardware implementation - when you use them, the computer can perform substractions with the same hardware it performs additions and no special treatment is necessary.

Comment: I'm just reading that wiki page and it seems that there are lots of advantages over the way I thought it worked, which I think is 1s complement. It's just one of those non-intuitive things that we must come to accept I suppose! Quantum mechanics confused me in the beginning but now it is the only way I can see the world; curse you Newton I believed in you!

Answer (score 2):

The representation used is not sign-modulus, but yet 2-complement. Therefore, in order to know which number is represented by a sequence of bits that starts with one, you must subtract 1 and then invert. In your case you will get 1101_1111_1111_1110 inverted which will give 0010_0000_0000_0001 which is exatcly 8193. Therefore, there is no problem whatsoever - you just confused the nternal representation mechanism.